# logback: FileNamePattern from application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, logback

I would like to get the file name of my logback file from a property defined in the

```
application.properties
```

but I don't know if it is possible

```
<fileNamePattern>${user.home}/logs/>${logFileName}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your `application.properties` file in the `logback.xml` configuration file. logback will then recognize the properties defined in that file.

logback.xml:

```
<property resource="application.properties"/>
```

More details: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingProps